# Encrypt an existing SQL Server table column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way I can encrypt an existing column in a SQL Server table without changing any other systems which uses this column? I am on SQL Server 2005.

I guess it's possible in Oracle like this (after enabling `Transparent Data Encryption`)

```
ALTER TABLE employees    
    MODIFY (salary ENCRYPT USING '3DES168');
```

Comment: SQL Server **2005** is dead - past its prime - out of even extended support - you should **upgrade** to a more recent version as long as you still can!

Comment: @marc_s , so which version has data encryption

Comment: SQL Server supports [Transparent Data Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb934049) from 2008 onwards, but on the page level, not on the column level. On the column level, you can use a function like [`ENCRYPTBYKEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174361), but this is not transparent, although you could create a view on the encrypted column. You could do this without changing applications (though not without interruption) by renaming the base table, defining a view on it and giving this view the name of the original table. DML would be done through triggers.

Answer (score -2):

You can encrypt the data using PHP functions or any other scripting library functions and store them in the MySQL database. I hope this helps.

Comment: the question is precisely stated for SQL-Server.

Comment: This table is used by around 7 apps, so was looking for a quick fix than changing 7 apps